# Template specialization using typedefs

Tags: c++, templates, typedef, vulkan

While learning Vulkan I came across some code in the VulkanCookbook. in the VulkanCookbook the author writes the code to import the Vulkan functions and classes by hand. Well I've been slowly converting it over to the LunarG's SDK for Vulkan and I came across a problem in the under 64bit VkFence it typedef'd to VkFence_T* which is fine and all but in 32bit it's typedef'd as uint64_t which causes a problem for VkDestroyer which uses code similar to below

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef uint64_t A;
typedef uint64_t B;

template<typename T>
class Handler
{
    void DestroyObject( T parent );
};

template<>
inline void Handler<A>::DestroyObject(A object) {
  std::cout << "destroy type A" << std::endl;
}

template<>
inline void Handler<B>::DestroyObject(B object) {
  std::cout << "destroy type B!" << std::endl;
}

int main()
{}
```

is there any good way to handle this problem or do I have to go and rework all the example code to delete Objects by hand? I would like to compile under 32bit if possible.

Sorry if this question has been asked somewhere else I couldn't find it as google always came partial templating and other non-related topics. And I do understand the problem with the code the compiler is looking at _A and _B and just treating it a uint64_t without caring that they are named differently, which causes the DestroyObject overloads to be for the same template type causing the redefinition error.

Edit: fixed the code using invalid naming as that wasn't actually a core problem.

Comment: @StoryTeller (a) is there anyway of getting around that problem? (b) I changed that in the code I was testing I accidentally pasted the older version of that code.

Comment: Are the types strictly integral?

Comment: @StoryTeller yes and there are like 20 of them. Based on how they work I think they're used like 64bit pointers in 32bit mode.

Comment: Let me know if the solution I posted is feasible for you

Comment: @Cieric, hi! Sorry for the inconvenience! Now I see that I didn't do one of the most obvious things I should've done - I should test if it is possible to compile the whole code for x86 platform. Somehow I missed that!! I will think how to do it but, indeed, it may not be that easy.

Comment: @Ekzuzy At first I was didn't understand what you were saying but now I see you're the author of the vulkan cookbook. thanks for the help, I've looked at multiple examples and my biggest problem is making a dynamic system one where I can load in a model at any time and render it dynamically. This is all because I'm making a game engine as a learning experiance and I want to do vulkan as I already learned OpenGL and DirectX.

Comment: @Cieric Hi! I have finally fixed compilation problems for x86 targets. If You are still interested in building the code for Win32, You can check it now. But I still need to update CMakeLists.txt, so the Visual Studio solution is prepared with both x64 and x86 targets (now it only generates x64 target and the x86 has to be added manually).

Comment: @Ekzuzy Thank you so much, I've actually been holding off on Vulkan for a while because I couldn't wrap my head around it. This is a pretty good time to get back into it. Thank you for the hard work!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

C++ doesn't have strong typedefs. A type alias is simply another name for an existing type, and is entirely equivalent to the type it aliases, when used.

You need `A` and `B` to be actual types, not aliases, which are both in a relationship with `uint64_t`. So long as you constrain yourself to integral types, you can construct new distinct ones out of them.

The solution is an enumeration with an underlying type specified for it.

```
#include <type_traits>

template<typename E>
using argument_t = std::conditional_t<std::is_enum<E>::value,
                                      std::underlying_type_t<E>,
                                      E>; 

template<typename T>
class Handler
{
    void DestroyObject( argument_t<T> parent );
};

enum A : uint64_t {};
enum B : uint64_t {}; 

template<>
inline void Handler<A>::DestroyObject(uint64_t object) {
  std::cout << "destroy type A" << std::endl;
}

template<>
inline void Handler<B>::DestroyObject(uint64_t object) {
  std::cout << "destroy type B!" << std::endl;
}
```

The above works like this:

- The `argument_t` utility checks if `E` is an enumeration, and gives the underlying type for it. Otherwise it falls back to `E` itself.
- The primary template accepts a `T`, and transforms the argument if needed.
- Since `A` and `B` are **distinct** types now, you can specialize on each. The function accepts the underlying type as a parameter.

Comment: This solution is actually really nice however I'm unsure if changing the types A and B are feasible in my case as they are apart of the header included with the library. However as your response answers the question I will mark it as correct and just continue to compile in 64 bit where the problem doesn't exist.

Answer (score 0):

You almost have it right... What the above functions `Handler<_A>::DestroyObject(_A object)` and `Handler<_B>::DestroyObject(_B object)` actually are is concrete instantiations of a templated member function. Because the author did not provide a generic version of this function, you are having the issues you are with trying to instantiate the class with a uint32_t. The simple fix would be to write a `template<> void Handler<uint32_t>::DestroyObject(uint32_t o)` function. Without more context, I cannot offer better advice.

Comment: The problem is that typedef A and B are the same core type but I need different code to run based on the typedef type and not the core type. And a `template<> void Handler<uint32_t>::DestroyObject(uint32_t o)` can't work because the resulting code needs to be different based on the type passed in.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way for a template to distinguish between being pasded `A` and `B` as a type parameter.

There may be alternatives to manually cleaning up objects, but your question is too vague and focused on finding a way to get a non-viable solition working to determine what your problem really is.

Probably you have to disntinguish between the types using something different than the types themselves.

Comment: I mainly didn't want to majorly change up the code as I want to actually learn how to use Vulkan without to much hassle however as it is a problem I'll just continue to compile in 64 bit which does work.